# #DiscordWebhook Error 'Bad request signature' trying to connect on URL interaction endpoint

Tags: javascript, discord, discord-interactions

I'm developing an bot application in Javascript that uses a Discord webhook to return API data after to trigg a slash command. I'm basing myself on an example on the Discord Developer website (https://discord.com/developers/docs/getting-started), and its GitHub repository (https://github.com/discord/discord-example-app).
I just need some  functions and modules from the discord example, which will be used in the implementation, and today the app should return a simple text message. If it works, I'll implementate a fetch data for API.
To testing if it works, I start the app.js script, that is an Express app, and I use an URL generated by ngrok to set the endpoint interactions URL in settings of my Discord application. However, I can't set this URL, and my application crashes, givin an **bad request** error, associated with a **401 response status**. Probably is an error of mine that I can't find, the discord's example works fine.  In the utils.js script, there is a function that uses the **verifyKey** function, which belongs to the **discord-interactions** package . I think the problem is there. Below is the link to my repository on GitHub:
https://github.com/wiliansanello/te-quotations-by-discord/tree/master/poc-discord
Somebody can help me to fix this error, please? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem following the discord documentation, and yep... it was totally my fault for not reading all the documentation.

When you go to **General Information** in your app **Settings** to paste the "**INTERACTIONS ENDPOINT URL**", you have to append **/interactions** to the link

So it should be something like this:

```
https://example-your-url/interactions
```